# Definition of normal extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, splitting-field

Definition of normal extension on *Abstract Algebra* of Dummit and Foote:

> **Definition.** If $K$ is an algebraic extension of $F$ which is the splitting field over $F$ for a **collection** of polynomials $f(x)\in F[x]$ then $K$ is called a *normal* extension of $F$.
> We shall generally use the term ''splitting field'' rather than *normal* extension of $F$.

Is ''collection'' the difference between *normal extension* and *splitting field* ?
If there are finite polynomials in the collection we can just identify the extension as the splitting field of the product of polynomials in the collection, if there are infinite polynomials we cannot identify the extension as a splitting field and that's the reason of using the term ''collection''.

Is my understanding right? If so, why can we substitute ''splitting field'' for ''normal extension'' ?

Comment: Usually when we discuss splitting fields, we talk about the splitting field of a specific polynomial, or a specific collection of polynomials. A normal extension is just an extension which is the splitting field of some arbitrary collection of polynomials. It can be easily proved that a finite normal extension is always the splitting field of one polynomial. (you pretty much explained the reason in your question)

Comment: @Mark So the difference between ''splitting field'' and ''normal extension'' is just that one is specific and another is abstract, there is also ''splitting field'' of a infinite collection of polynomials. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.

Comment: Usually $K$ is the splitting field of $f\in F[x]$ means that $f$ splits completely in $K$ and $K=F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ where $a_j$ are the roots. And $K/F$ (a finite extension) is normal means that for every $b\in K$, its $F$-minimal polynomial splits completely in $K$. Then it is a theorem that both are equivalent.